# Qt QHash iterator

Tags: c++, qt

I have my code:

```
for(QHash<long,float>::iterator i=list.begin();i!=list.end();++i)
{
    long id = QVariant((*i).key()).toLongLong();
    float ile = QVariant((*i).value()).toFloat();
}
```

and i become this error:

```
request for member 'key' in 'i.QHash<K,V>::iterator::operator*<long int, float>()', which is of non-class type 'float'    
             long id = QVariant((*i).key()).toLongLong();
```

How to convert `key()` and `value()` to my `float` and `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member methods `key` and `value` are part of the iterator's interface.
Because of that, it should be enough to use `i.key()` instead of `(*i).key()`.
The same applies for `values`, for which you should use `i.value()` instead of `(*i).value()`.
The `operator*` of the iterator returns a reference to the *i-th* value, in your case to a `float` that has not the member methods `key` and `value` indeed.

The assignments should resemble the following ones:

```
long id = i.key();
float ile = i.value();
```

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash-iterator.html) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

`key()` and `value()` are methods of the iterator, so you access them like this:

```
    long id = QVariant(i.key()).toLongLong();
    float ile = QVariant(i.value()).toFloat();
```

`*i` is same as `i.value()`, so you could also write `QVariant(*i)` for the value.

You get the error you get, because the line of the error is same as this: `long id = QVariant(i.value().key()).toLongLong();`, and obviously the `float` value is a non-class as said in the error, so it can't have `key()` method (or any other members).

Finally, going through the `QVariant` is totally unnecessary anyway (at least in this case), so you can just do this:

```
    long id = i.key();
    float ile = *i;
```

Doc reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash-iterator.html